# How to convert "2012-10-16T14:46:33+00:00" into Unix Timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, time, format, timestamp, converters

How do you convert a string in the format `2012-10-15T13:16:13+00:00` into a Unix Timestamp in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) should be able to handle it.

Example

```
echo strtotime("2012-10-15T13:16:13+00:00") ; // 1350306973
```

Or

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r '$d="2012-10-15T13:16:13+00:00"; print strtotime($d) . "\n";'
1350306973
```

Once you have a timestamp, you can do anything with it.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r '$d="2012-10-15T13:16:13+00:00"; $t=strtotime($d); print strftime("%+", $t)."\n";'
Mon Oct 15 09:16:13 EDT 2012
```

Comment: Sure, that completely fine.  I'm in the habit of showing things on command lines to help demonstrate that people can duplicate exactly what I've done on their own systems (and hopefully play with them), but early simplification is also very helpful.  :)

Comment: @Baba: Thank you.  Is there a function similar to `strtotime()` in the new DateTime class?  I couldn't find one...

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by **Baba** that uses the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$dt = new DateTime("2012-10-15T13:16:13+00:00");
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```